Error: You can't use the Send Conversation Messages action type in flows with the null trigger type
Im deploying into my sandbox. I get this error in an autolanched flow used to send whatsaap notifications:
You can't use the Send Conversation Messages action type in flows with the null trigger type.

Any idea? All in my origin sandbox is working fine.

Have you enabled all necessary WhatsApp configuration and permissions in your target sandbox?
